# widget area styling in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

iam a beginner level developer in wordpress..And now am converting my HTML template to wordpress theme and now am at sidebar and widget area.
I have created one widget area and sidebar and added my own widget ..Now everthing fine , But the problem is when am adding any other widget(third party widget) it's not getting the style of my wodget..Actually it's showing different styles.. the thirdparty widget have one style and my  widget have another(that i defined)

please help me in this issue

thank you

Comment: Check if you can customize the third party widget theme. There is no other possible way that I know of. And, try to implement custom widgets than using third party widgets.

Comment: no i have a theme ,if i added any third party widget in to it ,it will take the theme's style ... @aliasm2k

Answer (score 0):

It's easy thing to change. Find the CSS Class or ID of the third-party widget by using Firebug Addon for Firefox. Then define your own styles to stop the default Styles of the widget.

Comment: no, if am again adding another thirdparty widget what will i do?

Comment: If I can see your website, I can provide a better answer.